# Python parsing Protobuf Response from Web Socket

Tags: python, websocket, protocol-buffers

I'm using following scheme of proto, to interact with Server. `Python` Client using  [`WebSocket Client`](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client) to connect.

```
syntax = "proto3";
package messages;
import "any.proto";

// ................................

message GeneralResponse {
    oneof response {
        MainResponseA registrationResponse = 1;
        MainResponseB connectResponse = 2;
    }
}

message MainResponseA {
    bytes bytesA = 1;
    int64 timeLeave = 2; 
}


message GeneralMessage {
    fixed32 identifier = 1;
    oneof contents {
        GeneralResponse response = 1;
        GeneralState generalState = 2;
    }
}
// ................................
```

After successful connection and few requests (which are Ok), I'm getting next response in relevant method `on_message`.

```
@staticmethod
def on_message(ws, message):
    logging.debug("Source Message: %s \n \n", message)

    // 2) This lines parse Message and only identifier,
    //    not inner Response Objects, with other info

    gen_msg = messages.GeneralMessage()
    gen_msg.ParseFromString(message)
    logging.info('Received Msg: %s',
        gen_msg)
```

In source Message, as you can see below, I received some big encoded message.

```
    �"�R�2018 12:38:22 PM Source Message: 
    �   
    �   �PNG

    IHDRk�XTPLTE���U��~�IDATx����n$+����wg����SW"��8�YXeW#H�?J)��RJ)��RJ)��RJ)��RJ)��RJ�V����3Փϼ?��+�|<��%�U��O��\����wW�`9����Z ����X�%XH0���c��Q.L`
                                          ����VXW������CDWh�|�
    �3���$n-�io��P�fa��4�   �廖���fP���V��O�Kf�X�``
                                                    )L�����g9�����=� ��v��2w��c���( �gk��#���SVa�jc&Kp�7!~��IR�            
  // And so on ............
```

Later after parsing this into Protobuf  Object, I have only identifier! And no inner Objects, where I suppose to have fields `bytesA` and `timeLeave`. Any ideas, what is wrong here?

```
07/06/2018 12:38:22 PM Received Msg: identifier: 1387340418
response {
  registrationResponse {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was in unsynced version of Protobuf Scheme with Server. And they sent a objects with another fields in inner Response.